# How to set the limit of cpu per user using maxTRESperuser on qos for slurm

Tags: slurm

I just set the qos parameter MaxTRESperuser to cpu=10 for testing purpose, but slurm is schedulling the job.

I used:

```
sacctmgr modify qos normal set maxtresperuser=cpu=1
```

and we can view on

## sacctmgr show qos

```
  Name   Priority  GraceTime    Preempt PreemptMode                                    Flags UsageThres UsageFactor       GrpTRES   GrpTRESMins GrpTRESRunMin GrpJobs GrpSubmit     GrpWall       MaxTRES MaxTRESPerNode   MaxTRESMins     MaxWall     MaxTRESPU MaxJobsPU MaxSubmitPU     MaxTRESPA MaxJobsPA MaxSubmitPA       MinTRES 

normal          0   00:00:00                cluster                                                        1.000000                                                                                                                                        cpu=1
```

but all the jobs sent from the same user were allocated, each job using 2 cpus

## squeue

```
         JOBID PARTITION     NAME     USER ST       TIME  NODES NODELIST(REASON)
           370     teste script.s     root  R       0:11      1 slurmcomputenode2.novalocal
           371     teste script.s     root  R       0:11      1 slurmcomputenode2.novalocal
           372     teste teste.sh     root  R       0:07      1 slurmcomputenode1.novalocal
```

The slurm documetantion doesn't say anything else about it.
Do I need to change something on slurm.conf file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure `AccountingStorageEnforce` is set to `limits,qos`. You also need proper accounting for limits to be enforced. See the [documentation](https://slurm.schedmd.com/resource_limits.html).